# Understanding the output of gettimeofday

Tags: c, linux, gettimeofday

I am trying to understand the precision of the `gettimeofday()` system call. Here's my program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct timeval t;
    int prev = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < atoi(argv[1]); i++)
    {
        gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
        printf("secs: %ld, nmicro_secs: %d, delta: %d\n", t.tv_sec, t.tv_usec, t.tv_usec - prev);
        prev = t.tv_usec;   
        sleep(1);
    }   

    return 0;
    
}
```

The output if I run this program (`./a.out 10`) is,

```
secs: 1643494972, nmicro_secs: 485698, delta: 485698
secs: 1643494973, nmicro_secs: 490785, delta: 5087
secs: 1643494974, nmicro_secs: 491121, delta: 336
secs: 1643494975, nmicro_secs: 494810, delta: 3689
secs: 1643494976, nmicro_secs: 500034, delta: 5224
secs: 1643494977, nmicro_secs: 501143, delta: 1109
secs: 1643494978, nmicro_secs: 506397, delta: 5254
secs: 1643494979, nmicro_secs: 509905, delta: 3508
secs: 1643494980, nmicro_secs: 510637, delta: 732
secs: 1643494981, nmicro_secs: 513451, delta: 2814
```

The seconds column seems to reconcile with the sleep of 1 secs. Can someone please explain what's going on with the values in micro seconds column? It looks like the jumps from sleep to sleep are ~ 1 millisecond.

Comment: This program measures scheduling jitter, which on Linux is expected to be order of 1 millisecond since the scheduling clock ticks at 1024 Hz (iirc). You have to do something much more complicated to measure the accuracy of the clock itself -- have a look at the source code to [chrony](https://chrony.tuxfamily.org/) for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calculating the difference between two consecutive calls only using the `.tv_usec` field. In other words, you are discarding the `.tv_sec` field, and therefore if the first measurement yields `.tv_sec=1, .tv_usec=500000` (meaning 1.5s since epoch) and the second one yields `.tv_sec=2, .tv_usec=500000` (meaning 2.5s since epoch) your `delta` would be exactly `0`, which is wrong.

You have to take into account the entire value: `t.tv_sec * 1000000 + t.tv_usec`. Only then you can calculate a meaningful difference. Note that you will need a type larger than `int` to hold this value. Something like `uintmax_t` should be adequate. Or, [as @zwol suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70910268/understanding-the-output-of-gettimeofday/70910334?noredirect=1#comment125356719_70910334) in the comments, two different `struct timeval` if you want to calculate the difference without an intermediate type.

> I am trying to understand the precision of the `gettimeofday()` system call

In any case, none of what you are doing will tell you the *precision* of `gettimeofday`, which is a different thing. Sleeping between two syscalls will make your process inactive for a not-so-deterministic amount of time.

Comment: In context (OP is trying to measure clock jitter) it makes sense to work in microseconds of *residual*, i.e. calculate `((cur.tv_sec - 1) - prev.tv_sec) * 1000000 + cur.tv_usec - prev.tv_usec` which should stay comfortably within the range of int(32_t). Also, in the common case where `cur.tv_sec == prev.tv_sec + 1`, it's the same as what OP did.

Comment: Linux (Well, glibc) has [`timersub()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/timeradd.3.html) for subtracting two timevals and storing the result in a third.